# vapply: values must be length 11

Tags: r

I'm using the function `drive_time()` from the `placement` package by Derek Darves, which outputs the time and length between two points via Google Maps.

However, not even the example code works for me:

```
howfar_kms <- drive_time(
address="350 5th Ave, New York, NY 10118, USA",
dest="1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043",
auth="standard_api", privkey="", clean=FALSE,
add_date='today', verbose=FALSE, travel_mode="bicycling",
units="imperial"
)
```

It gives this error:

> Error in vapply(json, function(x) { :
>   values must be length 11,
>        but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 0

It should be noted that yesterday the very same piece of code worked. I guess this is a problem of being dependent on things like real-time traffic info and so on.

Anyway I don't know how to work it out because `vapply` is part of the inner working of the function I guess.

Do you have any idea?

This is the full function, thanks @lmo for the tip.

```
function (address, dest, auth = "standard_api", privkey = NULL, 
    clientid = NULL, clean = "TRUE", travel_mode = "driving", 
    units = "metric", verbose = FALSE, add_date = "none", language = "en-EN", 
    messages = FALSE, small = FALSE) 
{
    options(stringsAsFactors = F)
    if (!grepl("standard_api|work", auth)) 
        stop("Invalid auth paramater. Must be 'standard_api' or 'work'.")
    if (is.null(privkey)) 
        stop("You must specify a valid API key or an empty string (''). To request a key, see:\n\t https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#get-an-api-key")
    if (auth == "work" & is.null(clientid)) 
        stop("You must specify a client ID with the work authentication method!")
    if (!grepl("driving|bicycling|transit|walking", travel_mode, 
        ignore.case = TRUE)) 
        stop("You must specify a valid travel mode.")
    if (!grepl("metric|imperial", units)) 
        stop("Invalid units paramater. Must be 'metric' or 'imperial'")
    if (length(address) > 1 & length(address) != length(dest)) 
        stop("Address must be singular or the same length as destination!")
    if (!is.vector(c(address, dest), mode = "character")) 
        stop("Address and destination must be character vectors!")
    if (!grepl("today|fuzzy|none", add_date)) 
        stop("Invalid add_date paramater. Must be 'today', 'fuzzy', or 'none'")
    if (privkey == "" & travel_mode == "transit") 
        stop("You must specify a valid API key to use the transit mode!")
    if (!is.logical(messages)) 
        stop("messages must be logical! Please choose TRUE or FALSE.")
    if (clean) {
        if (verbose) 
            cat("Cleaning origin addresses...\n")
        address <- placement::address_cleaner(address, verbose = verbose)
        if (verbose) 
            cat("Cleaning destination addresses...\n")
        dest <- placement::address_cleaner(dest, verbose = verbose)
    }
    not_nambia <- function(x) {
        x[is.na(x)] <- ""
        return(x)
    }
    address <- not_nambia(address)
    dest <- not_nambia(dest)
    enc <- urltools::url_encode(address)
    dest <- urltools::url_encode(dest)
    if (auth == "standard_api") {
        inbound <- data.frame(address = enc, dest = dest)
        baserl <- "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="
        inbound$full_url <- paste0(baserl, inbound$address, "&destinations=", 
            inbound$dest, "&units=", tolower(units), "&mode=", 
            tolower(travel_mode), "&language=", language, "&key=", 
            privkey)
        togoogle <- inbound$full_url
    }
    if (auth == "work") {
        togoogle <- placement::google_encode64(enc, dest = dest, 
            gmode = "dtime", privkey = privkey, clientid = clientid, 
            verbose = verbose, units = units)
    }
    if (verbose) 
        cat("Sending locations (n=", length(togoogle), ") to Google for distance calculation...\n", 
            sep = "")
    json <- placement::pull_geo_data(togoogle, tmout = 10, messages = messages)
    if (json[[1]]$status == "REQUEST_DENIED") {
        stop(paste0("Request sent to Google, but response returned REQUEST_DENIED.  Error details:\n", 
            json[[1]]$error_message))
    }
    coord <- t(vapply(json, function(x) {
        if (!is.null(x$status)) {
            if (x$status == "OK") {
                if (!is.null(x$rows$elements[[1]]$status)) {
                  if (x$rows$elements[[1]]$status == "OK") {
                    origin <- as.character(x$origin_addresses)
                    destination <- as.character(x$destination_addresses)
                    dist_num <- as.character(x$rows$elements[[1]]$distance$value/1000)
                    if (units == "imperial") 
                      dist_num <- as.character(as.numeric(dist_num) * 
                        0.621371)
                    dist_txt <- as.character(x$rows$elements[[1]]$distance$text)
                    time_secs <- as.character(x$rows$elements[[1]]$duration$value)
                    time_mins <- as.character(as.numeric(time_secs) * 
                      0.0166667)
                    time_hours <- as.character(as.numeric(time_secs) * 
                      0.000277778)
                    time_txt <- as.character(x$rows$elements[[1]]$duration$text)
                    return_stat <- as.character(x$rows$elements[[1]]$status)
                    status <- as.character(x$status)
                    error_message <- ""
                    return(c(origin, destination, dist_num, dist_txt, 
                      time_secs, time_mins, time_hours, time_txt, 
                      return_stat, status, error_message))
                  }
                  else {
                    return(c(as.character(x$origin_addresses), 
                      as.character(x$destination_addresses), 
                      rep(NA, 6), x$rows$elements[[1]]$status, 
                      x$status, ""))
                  }
                }
            }
            else if (x$status == "CONNECTION_ERROR" & !is.null(x$error_message)) {
                return(c(rep(NA, 9), x$status, x$error_message))
            }
        }
        else {
            return(c(rep(NA, 10), "Non-conforming response object: check source data/url for this record"))
        }
    }, character(11)))
    if (is.matrix(coord)) {
        out <- as.data.frame(coord)
    }
    else if (length(coord) == 11) {
        out <- data.frame(t(unlist(coord)))
    }
    colnames(out) <- c("origin", "destination", "dist_num", "dist_txt", 
        "time_secs", "time_mins", "time_hours", "time_txt", "return_stat", 
        "status", "error_message")
    nums <- c("dist_num", "time_secs", "time_mins", "time_hours")
    out[, nums] <- vapply(out[, nums], function(x) {
        x <- round(as.numeric(x), digits = 2)
        return(x)
    }, numeric(nrow(out)))
    out$input_url <- togoogle
    if (small) 
        out <- out[, c("dist_num", "time_hours")]
    if (!add_date == "none") {
        out$geocode_dt <- Sys.Date()
        if (add_date == "fuzzy") 
            out$geocode_dt <- out$geocode_dt + stats::runif(nrow(out), 
                1, 30)
    }
    if (verbose) {
        cat("Finished.", nrow(out[out$return_stat == "OK", ]), 
            "of", nrow(out), "distance calculations were successful.\n")
        if (units == "imperial") {
            len <- "miles"
        }
        else {
            len <- "kilometers"
        }
        message("Note: numeric distances in the 'dist_num' column are expressed in ", 
            len, ".\n")
    }
    return(out)
}
```

Comment: I think it is because `drive_time` can't find a match with the address.

Comment: You can often take a look at the the underlying code by typing the name of the function without the parentheses. For example, `drive_time`, not `drive_time()`. Then look for `vapply`.

Comment: Just tried it and I cant reproduce the error.

Comment: I've just added the code within the function.